# Using Regular Expressions with PHP to replace text

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is something like `"apple|banana|peach|cherry"`.

How can I use regular expressions to search this list and replace another string with a certain value if there is a match?

For example:

```
$input = 'There is an apple tree.';
```

Change that to: `"There is an &lt;fruit>apple&lt;/fruit> tree."`

Thanks,
Amanda

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<?php
$patterns ="/(apple|banana|peach|cherry)/";

$replacements = "<fruit>$1</fruit>";

$output = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, "There is an apple tree.");
echo $output;
?>
```

For more details please look at the [php manual on preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Update:
@Amanda: As per your comment you may modify this code to:

```
$patterns ="/(^|\W)(apple|banana|peach|cherry)(\W|$)/";
$replacements = "$1<fruit>$2</fruit>$3";
```

to avoid matching impeach and scrapple

Answer (score 0):

[preg_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Although, if you want to match directly, it's faster to use str_replace or str_ireplace like that:

```
$text = "some apple text";
$fruits = explode("|", "apple|orange|peach");
$replace = array('replace apple', 'replace orange', 'replace peach');

$new = str_replace($fruits, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful! Is there a way to keep words like IMPEACH or SCRAPPLE from getting tagged as fruits?

Comment: @Amanda: As per your comment you may modify my code above to:

$patterns ="/(^|\W)(apple|banana|peach|cherry)(\W|$)/";
$replacements = "$1<fruit>$2</fruit>$3";

to avoid matching impeach and scrapple

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = 'There is an apple tree.';
$output = preg_replace('/(apple|banana|peach|cherry)/', "<fruit>$1</fruit>", $input);
```

Comment: Got it:$input = 'There is an apple tree.';
$output = preg_replace('/(apple|banana|peach|cherry)/', "<fruit>$1</fruit>", $input);

Answer (score 0):

Overall there is probably a better way to do this, but that would involve you giving a lot more details about your setup and overall goal.  But you can do this:

```
$input = preg_replace('~(apple|banana|peach|cherry)~','&lt;fruit>$1&lt;/fruit>',$input);
```